# Como modificar partes específicas dentro de um arquivo html?

Tags: php, codeigniter, regex, url, preg-match

Estou carregando um arquivo html e gostaria de modificar urls dentro dele para que o sistema reconheça o caminho real de cada arquivo que o html está tentando acessar, então eu tenho várias urls diferentes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css">      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css">

// Function
public function index()
{
    $layout = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $arquivo = read_file("/public_html/application/views/porto/{$layout}.php");
```

Gostaria de envolver estas urls com `<?php echo base_url("urlaqui") ?>` mas não consigo fazer isso. Alguém pode me ajudar??

Explicando melhor, eu gostaria de modificar as urls que estão dento do html sendo que o que eu tenho e o resultado final seguem abaixo:

```
// O que eu tenho ...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">

// O que eu preciso ...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"); ?>">
```

Comment: Olá, dá para explicar melhor o problema ?

Comment: @Edilson escrevi ali no final da pergunta algo que deve resumir. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Você só quer mudar as urls dentro do href? Tem alguma coisa em comum entre todas as urls que você quer mudar?

Answer (score 1):

Caro, você pode fazer isso com o notepad++ https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.3.3.html

Abra seu arquivo com ele e dê crtl+H, no modo de busca escolha "expressão regular".

```
Localizar: (href=")(.*)(">)

Substituir por: \1<?php echo base_url\("\2"\); ?>\3
```

Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Usando o `sed` fica assim:

```
sed -r 's/href="(.*)"/href="<?php echo base_url("\1"); ?>"/' arquivo-html >> novo-html
```

Onde:

> arquivo-html = Seu arquivo que você deseja alterar as urls
>
> novo-html = Novo arquivo criado no diretório atual com as urls corrigidas.

Saída:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"); ?>">      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css"); ?>">      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"); ?>">
```